# How to detect that quick sort algorithm has sorted all the elements?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures, quicksort

I know it sounds weird but, I'm developing an application in which I have to perform some action when quicksort is done sorting the array and I need to find any relation between start index or end index or the pivot or anything that can tell me that this is going to be the last partition/swap needed to sort the array...

```
fun quickSort2(arr: ArrayList<Int>, start: Int, end: Int, from: String) {
if (start >= end) return
val p = partitions(arr, start, end , from)
quickSort2(arr, start, p - 1, "first")
quickSort2(arr, p + 1, end, "second")
}
```

**partition** function:

```
fun partitions(arr: ArrayList<Int>, start: Int, end: Int , from: String): Int {
val pivotValue = arr[end]
var pivotIndex = start
for (i in start until end) {
    if (arr[i] < pivotValue) {
        swap(arr, i, pivotIndex)
        pivotIndex++
    }
}
swap(arr, pivotIndex, end)
return pivotIndex
}
```

**swap** function:

```
fun swap(arr: ArrayList<Int>, i: Int, pivotIndex: Int) {
val temp = arr[i]
arr[i] = arr[pivotIndex]
arr[pivotIndex] = temp
}
```

Can there be any relation like `if(start <= something && end <=someting)` anything that can tell that yes this is going to be the last swap or last partition or this is when the array is sorted, or I could calculate using the size that this many times partition will get called, anything that can tell me that at this stage array is sorted,

Comment: Your problem is about communicating between threads, and has nothing to do with quicksort.  When the sorting thread is done, it should inform the waiting thread.  If the waiting thread just wants to do periodic checks, then the sorting thread can just set a volatile/atomic boolean variable that it can see.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to check anything : just call `quickSort2` once, on the complete array.
Once this call returns, you can be sure the whole array has been sorted.

This is because `quickSort2` always calls itself on a smaller sub-array and there's a check if the sub-array is empty (`if (start >= end) return`).

To be sure it's the case, you could add some logging information at the start of `quickSort2`, displaying the input parameters.

Comment: I tried that, but actually, in my main application I'm using threads and delay to visualize algorithms, and the statement I want to execute after the quick sort is completed executes even when my sorting is still happening

Comment: @RahulPawar It sounds like you have a race condition ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition ). You might want to search for "parallel quicksort/merge-sort", because you'll probably only run into problems if you launch the above code in multiple threads. http://parallelcomp.uw.hu/ch09lev1sec4.html for example.

Comment: You can move the call to quicksort2 to its own function that has just two lines. In that function have the first line call quicksort2 syncrhonously in the second line set a done flag to true. In the rest of the code, where you want to check if the data is done sorting, just check that flag.  This is a simple but not efficient polling mechanism. You could improve it with events.